# ADMIN-DUPLICATECONFIGITEM: data base resource “hrhub-content” already content database “element- attribute-range-index

Tags: marklogic

I am trying to create a script to add element- attribute-range-index and element –range-index from a config  file . please find below the script for the same.
I am able to add  element-range-index but not able to add element- attribute-range-index  via the script or through the admin console UI also .

**Note:** I have cross-checked and there is no duplicate index available for this . I have freshly created .Still facing the same issue.

```
import module namespace admin :="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" 
                                 at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy"

let $dbid   := xdmp:database("hrhub-content")
let $config :=admin:get-configuration()
let $rangespec:= admin:database-range-element-attribute-index("string","www.aetna.com/hrhub/nm","plocalname","","pname","",fn:false())

return 
 let $new-index  := admin:database-add-range-element-attribute-index($config,$dbid,$rangespec)
return admin:save-configuration-without-restart($new-index)
```

> Error message: ADMIN-DUPLICATECONFIGITEM: (ERR:FOER0000) data base
>   resource “hrhub-content” already content database “element-
>   attribute-range-index”

Answer (score 1):

Your script contains some syntax errors. I have tried with the below and it worked for me:

```
import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";

let $dbid   := xdmp:database("hrhub-content")
let $config := admin:get-configuration()
let $rangespec:= admin:database-range-element-attribute-index("string", "www.aetna.com/hrhub/nm", "plocalname", "", "pname", "http://marklogic.com/collation/", fn:false())

return 
 let $new-index := admin:database-add-range-element-attribute-index($config,$dbid,$rangespec)
 return admin:save-configuration-without-restart($new-index)
```

Things I have changed:

- import changed `:=` to only `=`.
- import needs a `;` at the end.
- `admin:database-range-element-attribute-index` needs a collation if scalar-type is "string".

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your response. I did the same but  accidently I have missed to add these changes .Still I am facing the same issue. Did you try to run this query against  pre-configured "Documents" Database?

Comment: Yes, i ran that code against my Documents database and it ran successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the code that Wagner had pasted with the one change being

`let $dbid   := xdmp:database("*Documents*")`

and it worked. When I rerun the code I get the error that you are seeing ADMIN-DUPLICATECONFIGITEM, which makes sense since the index is already present. You may want to check if the index exists via this code -

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";

let $dbid   := xdmp:database("Documents")
let $config := admin:get-configuration()

return admin:database-get-range-element-attribute-indexes(
   $config,
   $dbid)
```